# Number formatting as-you-type in an input field in Angular2 with double binding

Tags: angular, input, format, currency

With pipes like

```
<input....
    [ngModel]="whatever | myCurrencyPipe"
    (ngModelChange)="whatever = $event"
    type="text"
    name="myCurreny"
    ...
```

you can format an existing value. Scarcely you want to overwrite the value, you have problems. And with the solution above, the double binding has been abrogated.

There are plenty of [jQuery-Libraries](https://github.com/customd/jquery-number) but I am looking for native angular2 solutions.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What is exactly your question, can you elaborate please? Thanks!

Comment: something like that: https://github.com/customd/jquery-number for Angular2

Comment: Have you looked into [text-mask](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/angular2#readme)? It [can be formatted](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/blob/master/componentDocumentation.md#mask) to mask the value of currencies.

Comment: thank you @Roy, it is good enough to start with,..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Extend NgModel directive. Overwrite function viewToModelUpdate(value) called after every input change and setting the model value.
2. Replace NgModel to your implementation (providers[] in module)
3. Read regexp or filter or formatter from specified attribute, directly on input like: < input filter="currency" />

Working example you can find here:
http://stacktrase.com/2017/07/14/angularjs4-restrict-input-text-by-extending-ngmodel/