# How to apply pipe on angular 2 formcontrolname

Tags: angular, pipe, form-control

I am applying number pipe on my formcontrolname. The formcontrolname has value on some action in html.
When the form loads it has empty value.
Below is my code, I see the error below when loading the screen.

When tempValue is 123, I need to display 123.00
If value is 777.45, I need to display 777.45

```
<input  type="number" formControlName="{{tempValue | number:'3.2'}}"  id="tempValue" name="tempValue" >
```

ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object HTMLInputElement]' for pipe 'DecimalPipe'

Answer (score 0):

`formControlName` is used to map the input field to the definition of your `FormGroup`, it's not meant for defining the formatting of the input field.

As far as I know, formatting input fields is something that is not currently supported by Angular out-of-the-box. You can however create a directive that formats it as you want to, like they do in [this article](http://www.tomastrajan.com/2016/07/28/custom-input-formatting-with-simple-directives-for-angular-2/). I also found [someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40038245/number-formatting-as-you-type-in-an-input-field-in-angular2-with-double-binding) that tried to do this.

A more important question for me though, are you sure you want to format the value *inside the input field*? In general, users tend to find this quite annoying. If you were to simply only format the value somewhere else on the page, your problem would not be a problem anymore:

```
<input type="number" formControlName="tempValue" id="tempValue" name="tempValue">
Value entered: {{yourForm.value.tempValue | number:'3.2'}}
```